# How to prevent server-side automerge in git

Tags: git

If for example I've pulled changes from remote, then commit and push my changes, and while I was commiting, somone else pushed another commit, that has no conflicts with my commit a new anonimouse branch will be created and our two commits will be merged. Is there any way to prevent creating this branch and automerging, so the server reject push as it will be with conflicts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git will not do this. If somebody `push`ed while you were working your `push` will fail due to not being *fast-forward*. You will recognise it by the

```
! [rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)
```

error message.

**You then need to `pull` first** (which does a `merge` on your client side). Afterwards your `push` will be a fast-forward and will succeed.

```
git push origin master  # FAILED
git pull origin master  # this does a merge on your client
git push origin master  # OK
```

Also read [Dealing with non-fast-forward errors](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-non-fast-forward-errors/).

Answer (score 0):

> a new anonimouse branch will be created and our two commits will be merged

No. `git` does not automatic merge while pushing. It requires that the head of the branch (on the receiving side) appears in the ancestry of whatever you are pushing right now (on the sending side), so it just appends your new commits on top of whatever is already there.

> Is there any way to prevent creating this branch and automerging,

Yes, `git` automatically informs you about a mismatch, with enough information for you to judge whether you simply need to do a `git pull` or whether things hit the fan (i.e., someone did a `git rebase ... ; git push -f` or a `git reset ... ; git push -f` or similar).